# Python Using Multiprocessing for the methods of the same Class

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-object

I need some help with multiprocessing module of python. I am using Python3.6.6. My code structure is somewhat like this:

```
class ABC():
    def __init__(self):
        self.HOST = 'hostserver.com'
        self.TCP_PORT = 0123
        self.BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
        self.SERVER_INFO = ""
        self.SOCK = None

    def connect_socket(self):
        self.SOCK = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.SOCK.settimeout(1)
        self.SOCK.connect((self.HOST, self.TCP_PORT))
        self.SOCK.setblocking(True)

    def recTask(self):
        while True:
            self.receive_data()
            time.sleep(0.01)

    def sendTask(self):
        while True:
            self.SOCK.sendall(bytes)
            print("\n*Message sent*\n")
            time.sleep(0.01)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    Class_obj = ABC()
    id = Class_obj.connect_socket()
    ts = mp.Process(name='send_Process', target=Class_obj.sendTask())
    ts.daemon = True    
    tr = mp.Process(name='rec_Process', target=Class_obj.recTask())
    tr.daemon = True
    tr.start()
    ts.start()
    ts.join()
    tr.join()
```

Can I call the methods of the same class using objects within the process? I want the 2 functions to run independently of each other. Also, when I run this I just see the "Message sent" being printed. In receive_data() function I have print("Message received") but it never prints. When I comment the code

```
ts = mp.Process(name='send_Process', target=Class_obj.sendTask())
ts.daemon = True
ts.start()
```

I see the "Message Received" being printed. Is there something which I am missing?

Comment: Please try without `ts.join()` and `tr.join()`.

Comment: Tried... still the same output

Comment: When I put tr = mp.Process(name='rec_Process', target=Class_obj.recTask()) on the top of  ts = mp.Process(name='send_Process', target=Class_obj.sendTask()) I see "Message Received" being printed. So basically whichever process I call first only it runs.